# Do conservative forces obey Newton's laws of motion? If we look closely, non-conservative forces like Friction etc follow 2nd law but Im confused

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, conservative-field

I have a small confusion, do conservative forces obey Newton's Second Law always?
Because it depends on the end points and the path taken, the acceleration may vary path to path, but the force doesnt depend on it, so IDEALLY it should defy it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *but the force doesnt depend on it* - this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Newton's second law states that the *net* force acting on an object equals its change in momentum. The net force can be any combination of conservative and non-conservative forces.

The difference between conservative and non conservative forces is the work done by conservative forces is path independent, i.e., it depends only on the initial and final positions, whereas the work done by non-conservative forces, like friction, is path dependent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for a conservative force with potential $U(\mathbf{r}$, the force is given by
$$
\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U(\mathbf{r}),$$
whereas the Newton's second law takes from
$$
m\mathbf{a}=\mathbf{F}=-\nabla U(\mathbf{r})
$$

Force changes along the path, but for any path taken between points $\mathbf{r}_i$ and $\mathbf{r}_f$ the change in the potential is
$$U(\mathbf{r}_f)-U(\mathbf{r}_i).$$